# Is there any public PeerServer over HTTPS?

Tags: github, peerjs

I have a simple web application using peerjs here: https://github.com/chakradarraju/bingo. I was planning to use github.io to put up a demo, and github.io will be served only in HTTPS, the default PeerServer that is used by the peerjs library doesn't support HTTPS.

Is there any public HTTPS PeerServer that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by setting options.secure to true as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/peerjs/https%7Csort:date/peerjs/M_fOCbQHf2s/ngRug7R5CAAJ).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this is no. It's unfortunate that the browsers recently disallowed http for any address except localhost.

One way to do it is set up an SSH port forward so that you can fool the browser into thinking it is talking to localhost. Ok for a demo, but not production. Here is some info (from https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example)

> In OpenSSH, remote port forwardings are specified using the -R option.
>   For example:
>
> ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 public.example.com
>
> This allows anyone on the remote server to connect to TCP port 8080 on
>   the remote server. The connection will then be tunneled back to the
>   client host, and the client then makes a TCP connection to port 80 on
>   localhost. Any other host name or IP address could be used instead of
>   localhost to specify the host to connect to.

Alternatively if you have your own web server, you can use Let's encrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/ to make it run https without needing to buy an SSL cert. Their tools are so good it's a five minute exersize to get https on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [www](http://go-www.com/)

Is can create automatically valid certificates by using letsencrypt or self-signed.

https://go-www.com/post/how-it-works/

```
Usage of ./www:
  -p port
        Listen on port (default 8000)
  -q quiet
        quiet mode
  -r root
        Document root path (default ".")
  -s your-domain.tld
        https://your-domain.tld if "localhost", port can be other than 443
```